Why are the upper half and lower half of the CMOS register value the same?
I used RW Everything to access the CMOS register values through Data/Index ports with 70/71 ports. There are 256 addresses in total, 0x00 ~ 0xFF.
I'm wondering why the upper 128 values (0x00~0x7F) are the same as the lower 128 values (0x80~0xFF) ? Is there any mechanism or principle behind it?


On many systems there are physically only 128 (on older systems it may have been 64) CMOS register values. Accessing beyond the last physical register wraps back to 0. This behaviour has been mentioned in the past: https://web.archive.org/web/20111209041013/http://www-ivs.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/~zbrog/asm/cmos.html
